How to fix a hole in a hollow closet door?
My kid pushed too hard against the closet door. Considering removing the door stopper altogether. I'm thinking of using spray foam with some Ready Patch or WoodEpox to fix it up. Open to better suggestions if anyone has them.


Or this? Repair a Hole/Crack in Hollow Core Door

Or this? How can I fix a hole in a hollow wooden door?

Hole repair on a budget depending on your wall . Stuff the hole with newspaper if it's large to fill in negative space. You can put a piece of masking tape or sheetrock tape then a little bit of sheetrock mud, wood filler, or caulk , sand , and paint
